# reverse of exponential sum in Excel

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula, statistics, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to find a way, in Excel, to work out the base number from the sum of exponential values.

For example there might be:

```
First number : 10
10 *  1.5 = 15
15 * 1.5 = 22.5
22.5 * 1.5 = 33.75
when you add these together you get 81.25
```

(It won't always be 1.5 and there may be more than 3 times it's multiplied)

I'm trying to work out a formula that will derive the first number (10) from the sum of the exponential values (81.25).

I'd appreciate any help at all on this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have [geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20geometric%20progression,number%20called%20the%20common%20ratio.) where

```
 a = 10
 q = 1.5
 n = 4 (you have 4 terms: 10, 15, 22.5 and 33.75)
```

And so the sum `s` (here `^` stands for raising into power) is

```
 s = a * (1 - q^n) / (1 - q)
```

In your case

```
 s = 81.25
```

To obtain `a` you can

```
 a = s * (1 - q) / (1 - q^n)
```

**Edit:** If I understand your last comment right "...*first* multiplier can be different, but *all the others* are the same..." you have

```
a
a * b
a * b * q
a * b * q^2
...
a * b * q^(n-2)
```

terms, and once again *geometric progression*:

```
s = a + a * b * (1 + q + q^2 + ... + q^(n-2)) =
  = a + a * b * (1 - q^(n - 1)) / (1 - q)
```

If we solve for `a` we'll have

```
a = s * (1 - q) / ((1 - q) + b * (1 - q^(n - 1)))
```

Comment: Sorry, I asked the wrong question.  The first multiplier can be different, but all the others are the same.  Can you help?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67366603/reverse-of-exp-sum-in-excel

Comment: Again, thank you so much for your help.

If you want to put this on the other question i linked then I'll mark it as +1 and accept it as the answer