# reverse of exponential sum

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, statistics

HELP!!!

I'm trying to find a way, in Excel, to work out the base number from the sum of exponential values. However, it's not as straight forward as that because the first multiplier is different to the others

For example there might be:

```
First number : 10
10 * 3 = 30
30 * 1.5 = 45
45 * 1.5 = 67.5
67.5 * 1.5 = 101.25
when you add these together you get 253.75
```

(It won't always be the same multipliers or the same number of times it's multiplied)

Given that I know what the multipliers are (3 for first and 1.5 for the rest) I'm trying to work out a formula that will derive the first number (10) from the sum of the other values (253.75).

I hope that makes sense

I'd appreciate any help at all on this!

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  1. there will be multiple solutions.  How do you select one of them?  2. The sum of the numbers you show = `243.75`, **NOT** `253.75`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

How do I select what, the multipliers? This varies depending on what i'm doing and they are known beforehand

I was including the first number in calculation so 253.75 is correct.

As there are 4 values known up front:
1) the total (including the first number)
2) the number of times the first number is multiplied
3) the amount it's multiplied by first
4) the amount it's multiplied by every other time

Comment: I asked this question previously 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67360833/reverse-of-exponential-sum-in-excel

but i've since realised that the first multiplier will change

Comment: Isn't the answer to this question still the answer to the other question you linked to, but simply divide by 3 (or whatever) at the end of it ?

Comment: I did think that it might be a simple as that but using the same formula and dividing by 3

(253.75 * (1 - 1.5) / (1 - 1.5^4))/3

I get a result of 10.41 which almost correct, but not quite

Comment: FYI Dmitry Bychenko has very kindly updated the other ticket with the formula to solve this problem.  Thank you Dmitry !

Comment: I didn't write that `253.75` was wrong, but that your sum of the four numbers does not add up to `253.75`.   I didn't realize that the first `10` was also added in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 3 (initial multiplier) is in the wrong place. Try this:

`=253.75 * (1 - 1.5) / ((1 - 1.5) + 3 * (1 - 1.5^(5-1))`

In the final `(5-1)`, the 5 is the total number of steps backward from the total that one would find the original number.